# Python: How to end game if number_of_guesses is 0?

Tags: python

I've got a small little project for a coursera course and we have to design a "Guess The Number Game". We've also been instructed to give 7 guesses if the number is 1-100 and 10 guesses if it is 1-1000. My code is below. I'm having some issues with my if statements. When guesses == 0, it still makes the user enter another input before telling him the game is over and starting a new game. I need it to say game over and reset when guesses == 0, without making the user guess again. Where am I going wrong here? I've tried setting elif number_of_guesses == 0 as well, with the same issue. Thanks in advance!

```
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    # initialize global variables used in your code here
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    print secret_number
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print ""
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 100!"

# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    number_of_guesses = 10
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if guess > secret_number and number_of_guesses > 0:
        print "Lower!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

    elif guess < secret_number and number_of_guesses > 0:
        print "Higher!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

    elif number_of_guesses > 0 and guess == secret_number:
        print "Correct!"
        new_game()

    elif number_of_guesses <= 1:
        print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
        new_game

    else:
        print "S**t, something went wrong here."

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number", 175, 175)

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame_input = frame.add_input("Your Guess: ", input_guess, 100)
range_100 = frame.add_button("Range 1 - 100", range100, 100)
range_1000 = frame.add_button("Range 1- 1000", range1000, 100)
frame.start()

# call new_game 
new_game()


# always remember to check your completed program against the grading rubric
```

**Edit**
I've also tried the code below this, with game_over() defines as it's own function. Apparently the issue is that I'm not checking for number of guesses remaining before getting input. I thought the nested if/else statements would solve this problem. Since they haven't, I'm clueless as to how to check this.

```
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    # initialize global variables used in your code here
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    print secret_number
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print ""
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 100!"

#helper function with game over as it's own function
def game_over():  
    print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    new_game()

# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    number_of_guesses = 10
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if number_of_guesses == 0:
        game_over()

    if guess > secret_number:
        if number_of_guesses > 0:
            print "Lower!"
            print ""
            number_of_guesses -= 1
            print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
            print ""

        elif number_of_guesses == 0:
            game_over()

    elif guess < secret_number:
        if number_of_guesses > 0:
            print "Higher!"
            print ""
            number_of_guesses -= 1
            print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
            print ""

        elif number_of_guesses == 0:
            game_over()

    elif guess == secret_number:
        if number_of_guesses > 0:
            print "Correct!"
            new_game()

        elif number_of_guesses == 0:
            game_over()

    else:
        print "S**t, something went wrong here."

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number", 175, 175)

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame_input = frame.add_input("Your Guess: ", input_guess, 100)
range_100 = frame.add_button("Range 1 - 100", range100, 100)
range_1000 = frame.add_button("Range 1- 1000", range1000, 100)
frame.start()

# call new_game 
new_game()
```

**Solution:** I was able to solve the issue on my own after debugging and getting furious for awhile. There were a lot of great answers to this post, with the most effective being the solution from Burhan. This code runs efficiently, but was not along the guidelines my class required, which is why I'm accepting my own answer as the solution, to aid my fellow classmates. Thanks to everyone who provided input, it was a great learning experience!

```
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    # initialize global variables used in your code here
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    print secret_number
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print ""
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 100!"

# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    number_of_guesses = 10
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if guess > secret_number:
        print "Lower!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

        if number_of_guesses == 0:
            print "Game Over! You Ran Out Of Guesses!"
            new_game()

    elif guess < secret_number:
        print "Higher!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

        if number_of_guesses == 0:
            print "Game Over! You Ran Out Of Guesses!"
            new_game()

    elif number_of_guesses == secret_number:
        print "Correct!"
        new_game()

    else:
        print "S**t, something's broken."
        new_game()

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number", 175, 175)

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame_input = frame.add_input("Your Guess: ", input_guess, 100)
range_100 = frame.add_button("Range 1 - 100", range100, 100)
range_1000 = frame.add_button("Range 1- 1000", range1000, 100)
frame.start()

# call new_game 
new_game()


# always remember to check your completed program against the grading rubric
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in my if/else statements. The solution was to nest an if statement inside of the guess, and check if there were any guesses left before proceeding. If there's not, it tells you your game is over, and resets. The completed solution is below.

```
# template for "Guess the number" mini-project
# input will come from buttons and an input field
# all output for the game will be printed in the console

import simplegui
import random

# helper function to start and restart the game
def new_game():
    # initialize global variables used in your code here
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    print secret_number
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print ""
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 100!"

# define event handlers for control panel
def range100():
    # button that changes the range to [0,100) and starts a new game 
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 101)
    number_of_guesses = 7
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def range1000():
    # button that changes the range to [0,1000) and starts a new game     
    global secret_number
    global number_of_guesses
    secret_number = random.randrange(0, 1001)
    number_of_guesses = 10
    print secret_number
    print "New Game! Current range is set to 0 - 1000!"

def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if guess > secret_number:
        print "Lower!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

        if number_of_guesses == 0:
            print "Game Over! You Ran Out Of Guesses!"
            new_game()

    elif guess < secret_number:
        print "Higher!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""

        if number_of_guesses == 0:
            print "Game Over! You Ran Out Of Guesses!"
            new_game()

    elif number_of_guesses == secret_number:
        print "Correct!"
        new_game()

    else:
        print "S**t, something's broken."
        new_game()

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Guess The Number", 175, 175)

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame_input = frame.add_input("Your Guess: ", input_guess, 100)
range_100 = frame.add_button("Range 1 - 100", range100, 100)
range_1000 = frame.add_button("Range 1- 1000", range1000, 100)
frame.start()

# call new_game 
new_game()


# always remember to check your completed program against the grading rubric
```

Comment: ,I'm glad you could get your problem sorted. I mentioned the exact workaround for your problem and I have tried to explain why this works in my answer. Hopefully, it would improve your understanding about the whole issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor your code quite a bit, for example place Game Over in it's own function.

The reason you ask another question is you are decrementing the number of guesses after input, but not checking this before getting the next guess from the user. One quick fix would be to check the number of guesses after validating their answer:

```
def game_over():  
      print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    new_game();
```

def input_guess(guess):
      # main game logic goes here
      global number_of_guesses
      guess = int(guess)
      print ""
      print "Guess was: ", guess
      print ""

```
  if guess > secret_number:
      print "Lower!"
      print ""
      number_of_guesses -= 1

  elif guess < secret_number:
      print "Higher!"
      print ""
      number_of_guesses -= 1

  elif number_of_guesses > 0 and guess == secret_number:
      print "Correct!"
      new_game()

  if number_of_guesses == 0:
      game_over();
  else: 
      print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
      print ""

  else:
      print "S**t, something went wrong here."
```

Still very messy, and untested but hopefully the logic makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain why your program lets the user put an extra guess before restarting the game based on your `if-else` statements.

Let's imagine a situation where the `number_of_guesses` is 2 and the user doesn't get it right this time. So it goes in one of the first two conditions of your `if` statement and the `number_of_guesses`is now 1. This is the last try that the user will be able to make. Again, imagining the user doesn't get it right on the last time even, your logic still takes him to one of the first two conditions of the `if` block which makes the `number_of_guesses` to be **ZERO** but does **NOT** restart the game.

You see? The deciding guess when you need to change the logic of your game is the last guess i.e. when the `number_of_guesses` == 1. So if you just do a check in the first two conditions where you reduce the number of guesses since the user gets it wrong like so:

```
 if guess > secret_number and number_of_guesses > 0:
    print "Lower!"
    print ""
    number_of_guesses -= 1
    print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
    print ""

    #Guesses become zero here, need to restart!
    if number_of_guesses == 0:
    print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    new_game

elif guess < secret_number and number_of_guesses > 0:
    print "Higher!"
    print ""
    number_of_guesses -= 1
    print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
    print ""

    #Guesses become zero here, need to restart!
    if number_of_guesses == 0:
    print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    new_game

elif number_of_guesses > 0 and guess == secret_number:
    print "Correct!"
    new_game()

elif number_of_guesses <= 1:
    print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    new_game

else:
    print "S**t, something went wrong here."
```

Of course there are several other ways you could modify your `if` statements. But I wanted to get this point across when you restructure it. This is the minimal check you need to do, in the last step. This should get your problem sorted. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JasonT.Eyerly, your current edit to the question with the nested `if-else` is still not working because of the reason I cited. There again, you're testing if `number_of_guesses` is **zero** in a nested `elif`. The problem happens after ` number_of_guesses -= 1` as that changes the value to 0 and it happens in that `if` block which is why it doesn't go the `elif` block. You don't need the `elif` condition there. Just check if the  `number_of_guesses` become zero after  `number_of_guesses -= 1` and end the game accordingly. Try the code snippet I shared. It should clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is check for the obvious conditions first, and fix your loop to remove all the same conditions to be in an outer loop.

I have switched you over to a while loop, so you don't need to check the number of guesses are greater than 0 each time:

```
def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if guess == secret_number:
        print "Correct!"
        new_game() 

    # We only need to run this loop, if the person
    # still has an guesses left
    while number_of_guesses > 0:
        if guess > secret_number:
            print "Lower!"
        if guess < secret_number:
            print "Higher!"
        print ""
        number_of_guesses -= 1
        print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
        print ""
        new_game()
    # If we reached here, it means there were no more guesses left
    game_over()
```

---

If you just want to do this with an if loop, you need to move all your conditions that can stop the game to the top of the function.

This function now does the following:

1. It accepts a variable `guess`
2. It converts this variable to an integer.
3. It checks if this variable `guess` is the same as the value of `secret_number`.
4. If it is, it will print "Correct", then start a new game, and stop executing further.
5. If the number of guesses is 0, it will end the game and stop executing further.
6. If the guess is higher than the secret number, it will print "Lower!"
7. If the guess is lower than the secret number, it will print "Higher!"
8. It will reduce 1 from the `number_of_guesses` variable.
9. It will print the number of guesses remaining, and stop executing further.

Now, you have this simple method:

```
def input_guess(guess):
    # main game logic goes here
    global number_of_guesses
    guess = int(guess)
    print ""
    print "Guess was: ", guess
    print ""

    if guess == secret_number:
        print "Correct!"
        new_game()

    if number_of_guesses == 0:
        game_over() 

    if guess > secret_number:
            print "Lower!"
    if guess < secret_number:
            print "Higher!"
    print ""
    number_of_guesses -= 1
    print "Guesses Remaining: ", number_of_guesses
```

The GUI framework will call this method each time changes the text field, which means it will run each time the text input is changed.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, as it never lets the user enter another guess. It just flies through the guesses using the same number and ends the game.

Comment: Where in your code are you asking the user to enter the number?

Comment: Add the bottom:

# register event handlers for control elements and start frame
frame_input = frame.add_input("Your Guess: ", input_guess, 100)

Comment: yes, so you only ask the user once - your program works in an event loop. It displays the user interface, then is waiting for an event (like a button click) to do something. So you have to write code so that the text field is cleared and a prompt is shown for the user to enter a guess again.

Comment: Is it possible to just use if/else statements? I'm in a beginner Python course and following a sort of outline. That being said, I'm not really sure how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

edit: checking if we have guesses should be the first thing we check.

```
if number_of_guesses == 0:
    print "Game Over! Out Of Guesses!"
    end_game()
elif condition:
    ...
    ...
elif condition:
    ...
    ...
else:
    print "Something went wrong"
```

Comment: I've tried that as well, as you will see in the most recent edit. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one buddy

```
import random

def game():
    LOWER = 1
    UPPER = 11
    secret = random.randrange(LOWER, UPPER)
    lives = 7
    while lives:
        guess = user_input()
        if secret == guess:
            print "You win!"
            break
        else:
            hint(secret, guess)
        lives -= 1
    else:
        print "Move along buddy. Game over."

def user_input():
    response = raw_input("Take a guess: ")
    return int(response)

def hint(secret, guess):
    if secret < guess:
        print "Your number is too big!"
    else:
        print "Your number is too small :("
game()
```

Let me know if you don't get anything.